# How to Keep Section Numbering but Not Include in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I would like have sections in the appendix numbered but not appearing in the table of contents.

If I use the `\section` command then the section is numbered and appears in the table of contents.  If I use the `\section*` command, then the section is removed from the table of contents but also the numbering is removed.  How I can keep the numbering?

Comment: Related (basically duplicate): [\setcounter{tocdepth}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59091)

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following code after `\section{}`

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
```

If you want the next chapter to be included in the TOC you just paste this code after this command and set the counter to 1

Comment: I changed the answer now because I found another solution